# Rich Text not rendering bullets in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, richtextarea

I have a custom lightning component which is embedded in a VF page. In this component, I am displaying rich text area content using **aura:unescapedHtml**

It is not working for **bullets**.

Following is the code:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!alert.value.relatedrecords}" var="rec">
    <dd class="slds-tile">
        <p class="tile__title red-txt">
            <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!rec.Message__c}"/>
        </p>   
    </dd>
</aura:iteration>
```

Is there any way to display the bullets in this lightning component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to add the slds-text-longform class to the p tag, e.g.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!alert.value.relatedrecords}" var="rec">
    <dd class="slds-tile">
        <p class="slds-text-longform tile__title red-txt">
            <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!rec.Message__c}"/>
        </p>   
    </dd>
</aura:iteration>
```

Taken from https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/text/